# Should I cross-develop for Linux under Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cross-platform

It seems that Visual Studio and the tools you can use it is far superior to Eclipse and other Linux-platforms.

So does it make sense to cross-develop for Linux under Visual Studio, as long as the code is much the same?

I assume that you can easily share files.

Of course it depends a lot of what you know and project setup, but for the later, importing to VS might be easier than importing into Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually possible, but only if you have the right infrastructure in place on both Windows and Linux (or some other *nix variety). I used to worke for an investment bank where almost all work was done on Windows with VC++ and then moved to Solaris and recompiled. This allowed us to use the far superior (over Solaris) Windows tools. And we are talking of building multi-tier, multi-threaded servers here.

However, in order to get this to work they had put in a massive effort (I would guess about 15 man-years)  in terms of senior developer time. And it was kind of worth it because Solaris development tools are pants (but the Linux ones are actually quite good). It's not something you, as an individual developer are going to find particularly easy to do, unless you are writing generic command line utilities. In which case you can do it - I routinely recompile my Windows command-line projects on Linux.

Comment: I did the same (Visual Studio/Solaris), but used the Qt infrastructure. Took us far less than a manyear to set up; perhaps 3 months. And that was for a project that used `imake`, which was already ancient a decade ago.

Answer (score 3):

The difficult part, in my opinion, is maintaining the separate build systems. If you start the project using Visual Studio you will be tempted to setup the project using the Visual Studio build system.

Don't do that.

Instead, I recommend trying [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). Make the build system build using CMake, and then work from that starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose between Visual Studio and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), I'd go with Emacs. The fact that Visual Studio seems superior to you is just because you got used to it and don't know how to do your usual workflow using other tools. Eclipse, after all, might not be the best choice for Windows developer to move to Linux. I'd also take a look at [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator).

Comment: @Neil: It was me who did that. People keep surprising how much they are willing to do just not to learn emacs. This time it is cross-compile.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: Did you mean vim? :)

Comment: the superiority of VS largely stems from it's debugger. Emacs didn't sport one last time I checked. Unfortunately, I don't have enough points to down vote this rubbish answer.

Comment: @rturrado: vim, too! And the beauty of `bash`, `sed`, `awk`, `gdb` and tons and tons of powerful tools! How can you trade that for a dumb visual studio where you cannot even properly manage multiple project`s settings? Uh, oh...

Comment: @user394460: Emacs has a pretty good gdb support, I don't think it's any worse than an IDE-based debugger: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7876

Comment: @loudandclear: It does. A good debugger support is also in CodeBlocks, KDevelop, Qt Creator... and possibly many others I haven't looked at.

Comment: Funny how someone can say that Emacs is underrated because people don't know it, and then continue to say how Visual Studio is unable to handle multiple project settings. You just inherit them. Which is BTW a 100 times easier then the hell which is called makefile.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: Oh, I have a friend on the Internet haha Tell me, I've spent a week, and still going, finding the correct configuration for a C#, C++/CLI project. Nightmare.